# Class-to-class communication design

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns

I'm working on a project that has a class structure like this:

```
class User {
  private data: any;

  public constructor() {
    this.data = {};
  }

  public set(data: any) {
    Object.assign(this.data, data);
  }
}

class RegistrationForm {
  public constructor(form: HTMLFormElement, user: User) {
    this.user = user;
    form.addEventListener('change', this.handleFormChange.bind(this));
  }

  private handleFormChange(e: Event): void {
    const key = e.target.getAttribute('name');
    const value = e.target.value;

    this.user.set({ [key]: value });
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way for them to communicate with each other. Passing instances of classes around is not ideal, as it makes testing confusing, verbose and unreliable. Singletons are also vague and unreliable, sure they make it so I don't have to pass instances around, but I'm also having to import the instance and use it so that doesn't quite alleviate my problem. Reinitializing singletons for every test is also tiresome.

The best solution I've thought of thus far is to emit and listen for events. Like this:

```
const user = new User();
const registrationForm = new RegistrationForm(document.querySelector('form'));

class User {
  private data: any;

  public constructor() {
    this.data = {};
    this.handleRegistrationFormEvents();
  }

  private handleRegistrationFormEvents(): void  {
    document.addEventListener('form:change', e => {
      Object.assign(this.data, e.detail);
    });
  }
}

class RegistrationForm {
  public constructor(form: HTMLFormElement) {
    form.addEventListener('change', this.handleFormChange);
  }

  private handleFormChange(e: Event): void {
    const key = e.target.getAttribute('name');
    const value = e.target.value;

    const customEvent = new CustomEvent('form:change', { [key]: value });
    document.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
  }
}
```

I like this because it makes testing very easy, and de-couples classes from dependencies. `RegistrationForm` doesn't care about the `Customer`, it just does what it needs to do and sends a signal to whoever does care.

My question is: is this the right way to go? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: what does `this.makeBInstances();` do? create a new instance of B? so it will still be tightly coupled. You could try implementing `interfaces`.

Comment: It creates multiple new instances of B. That would be the only way the classes get coupled.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with passing instances around, as long as your `B` class only requires an *`A`-like* object not a particular `A` instance (in short: define an interface). You could easily test your `B` by passing some mock object. The only thing that makes your classes tightly coupled is the `makeBInstances` call inside the constructor of `A`.

Comment: I just feel like that's messy. I don't want to say that `B` requires an `A`-like object, when in runtime it will always be an `A` instance except for testing. I also heard that it's best practice to make classes as de-coupled as possible, and with events, it seems you can do just that.

Comment: why does your `class A` need to hold the instance of `B`, its B who needs to call A's method?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't _need_ to hold the `B` instances. In the data that these classes take, `B`s belong to `A`s, so that's how I assumed the structure of the code could operate as well. I updated the question to reflect the change.

Comment: @Kyle You've discovered the mediator pattern :-) Now both of your classes depend on `document`, which is not necessarily better.

Comment: @Bergi That's true, however, the actual code behind these pseudo classes already depends on `document`. So I'm thinking that's okay? Although technically speaking now they depend on all the classes that support events too, but I would still rather that as opposed to my classes depending on each other.

Comment: @Kyle I think we would need a more concrete description of what the two classes are doing to judge which approach is most appropriate.

Comment: @Bergi just updated the question to be a lot more specific. There's still a lot more code than that, but hopefully this makes more sense. The latter solution is more verbose, but I can abstract the event handling to make it simpler.

Comment: I would still think the first one is more appropriate. A form should update a specific, single object, so it's natural to have a reference to it. The object doesn't necessarily need to be a `User`, any object with a `set()` method should suffice - make an interface for that, and you've decoupled them properly. The `User` class seems to be a plain entity class, it should not need to know about forms or documents.

Comment: I see now! So this interface would only include properties/methods of `User` that the `RegistrationForm` accesses, right? That would be nice since every interaction is explicitly laid out, which makes mocking easier and prevents me from accessing more of `User` without thinking about it first and adding it to the interface. Thanks for your insights :)